# Dropdown menu didn't drop as expected

Tags: html, css

I'm having a CSS problem with my Menu.

**Here is the screenshot of the dropdown menu:**
[image]

When hover The submenu it drops with the parent menu container. Please have a look and let me know whats wrong with it. Thanks for your help

**Here is my css code**

```
#menu {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #999;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
}

#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
}

#menu li a {
    display: block;
    min-width: 120px;
    padding: 10px 3px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 32px;
    font: bold 16px Lato, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    background: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #ececec;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu li a:hover {
    background: #ececec;
}

/*
Sub Menu (drop down)
*/

#menu li ul {
    display: none;
}

#menu li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}

#menu li ul li:hover {
    background: yellow;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    top: 50px;
}

#menu li ul li a {
    background: yellow;
    width: 150px;
    top: 50px;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-transform: none;
}

#menu li:hover ul {
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

And here is the Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fc69z/

Comment: Please make jsFiddle for the same. As it will be convenient to diagnose the same.

Comment: Should've added it before :) http://jsfiddle.net/Fc69z/

Comment: Check This: http://jsfiddle.net/Fc69z/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fc69z/3/)
I added this css:

```
#menu ul {
 list-style:none;
 position:fixed;
 display: inline-table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position:absolute` to the child `ul`, Like this,

```
#menu li:hover ul { 
width:150px; 
display: block; 
opacity: 1;  
visibility: visible; 
position:absolute; 
}
```

[FIDDLE HERE >>](http://jsfiddle.net/Fc69z/1/)

Comment: I've tried this, but it goes off within the main `ul` so i guess thats not i was looking. Now my issue has been resolved thanks for the help :)